# When is the optimal time to ask a question, or put a bounty on a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, statistics, bounty

Perhaps a dumb question, but I'm wondering if there is a better time of the week (or even day) to post a question, or put a bounty on a question to make sure it gets the most traffic. I assume responses to questions spike on weekends and evenings, but I really have no idea. Does anyone know, or know where I can see data that would give a clue? Thanks!

P.S.- I know we have contributors from many timezones, but I would expect there are still aggregate trends on when questions get the most traffic/input. Perhaps weekends and evenings in the US dominate, for example.

Comment: [There appear to be tools that can be used.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/213604/131640) I'm not sure if they're specific to SE.SP or over all stack exchange sites.